# Intel 7260 does not manually set frequency in 15.10 as it did in 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, firmware

I have been a Ubuntu user for some time and have come across a problem with using Ubuntu 15.10 with an Intel 7260 Wi-Fi chip for packet captures. I am unable to set the frequency in 15.10 as I have been in older versions of Ubuntu (14.04):

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down
sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 promisc
sudo iw dev wlp3s0 set freq 2412
```

none of the commands give me an error but the frequency is not applied:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

With a 14.04 partition on the same machine everything works fine:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

I have checked and all of the drivers are the same but the firmware is different.

Does anybody have any ideas?